# how to count length of aggregate before skip(pagination)

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose, aggregation-framework

I am building an api to get details of jobs and I need to do pagination for it. For pagination I need to get total number of pages, but I'm getting only skip pages. Please help me to get total number of pages before skip.

```js
let cJobs = await CrewbiesJobs.GetAllJobs();
let flashJobsResult = [];
let totalPages = 0;
let filter = {};
let queryLimit = parseInt(req.query.limit) || 10;
let pageNo = parseInt(req.query.page) || 1;
let query = {};
if (pageNo < 0 || pageNo === 0) {
  throw new CustomError('invalid page number, should start with 1', HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST);
}
query.skip = req.query.limit * (pageNo - 1) || 1;
query.limit = queryLimit;

let jobsAggregate = await Jobs.aggregate([{
    $lookup: {
      from: CrewbiesJobs.collection.name,
      localField: "jobId",
      foreignField: "jobId",
      as: "job_docs"
    }
  },
  {
    $unwind: "$job_docs"
  },

  {
    $project: {
      _id: 1,
      jobTitle: 1,
      jobId: 1,
      jobDescription: 1,
      postedDate: 1,
      filter1: 1,
      filter2: 1,
      filter3: 1,
      createdAt: 1,
      updatedAt: 1
    }
  },
  {
    $match: filter
  },
  {
    $skip: query.skip
  },
  {
    $limit: query.limit
  }


]).exec(function(err, doc) {
  if (err) {
    res.send(err);
  } else {
    totalPages = Math.ceil(doc.length / queryLimit);
    if (pageNo > totalPages) {
      throw new CustomError('Invalid page number', HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST);
    }
    console.log('matched jobs ', doc.length);
    res.json({
      msg: 'Jobs listed successfully',
      item: {
        totalPages: doc.length,
        currentpage: pageNo,
        jobs: doc
      },
      jobsCount: doc.length
    });
  }
});
}
catch (err) {
  CustomError.Handle(err, res);
}
```

*`totalPages`* counts should return 21 but am getting only 10 instead:

```
*{
  "msg": "Jobs listed successfully",
  "item": {
    "totalPages": 10,
    "currentpage": 1,
  },
  "jobsCount": 10
}*
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As far as I know you need to have a seperate query for total count.

The both aggregations have common stages so first I created the baseStages.
Then I added skip and limit stages to this base stage for the jobs data,  and added the count stage to the base stage to get total count of collections.

So you can try something like this:

```
const baseStages = [
  {
    $lookup: {
      from: CrewbiesJobs.collection.name,
      localField: "jobId",
      foreignField: "jobId",
      as: "job_docs"
    }
  },
  {
    $unwind: "$job_docs"
  },

  {
    $project: {
      _id: 1,
      jobTitle: 1,
      jobId: 1,
      jobDescription: 1,
      postedDate: 1,
      filter1: 1,
      filter2: 1,
      filter3: 1,
      createdAt: 1,
      updatedAt: 1
    }
  },
  { $match: filter }
];

const jobsStages = [
  ...baseStages,
  { $skip: query.skip },
  { $limit: query.limit }
];

let jobsAggregate = await Jobs.aggregate(jobsStages);

const countStages = [...baseStages, { $count: "COUNT" }];

let countAggregate = await Jobs.aggregate(countStages);
```

To construct the response I would console.log(countAggregate), and inspect where the count value resides, and use that value in response.

Comment: `Error: Arguments must be aggregate pipeline operators`                       getting this error in line
 `let jobsAggregate = await Jobs.aggregate(jobsStages);`

Comment: @SairamGouni I updated the answer, can you refresh and use the new code?

Comment: sah i am getting some duplicate values in pagination like in page1 if id is 21313 and it is also in page 2

Comment: @SairamGouni I think we can resolve this by adding sort to the baseStages

Comment: .i have issue with search .by above code am able to search only on first page itself i mean if i search with one word customer   ,with customer we have two titles .but now am getting only one value when i search ,i supposed to get both

Comment: ` if ('search' in req.query)
                filter = {
                    ...filter,
                    jobTitle: new RegExp(req.query.search, 'i')
                };`

Comment: @SairamGouni it must be related to your filter object,  I didn't change something there, I think this issue is not related with the answer.

Answer (score 1):

An option to make a single trip to `db` and get the count of documents is to use [**`$facet`**](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/facet/) which allows to process multiple aggregation pipelines. Since [**`$count`**](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/count/) wouldn't work with **`$addFields`** or **`$project`** in conjunction with the actual pipeline result.

**Query:** (After unwinding the `job_docs` do `$facet` stage)

```
Jobs.aggregate([
  {
    $lookup: {
      from: CrewbiesJobs.collection.name,
      localField: "jobId",
      foreignField: "jobId",
      as: "job_docs"
    }
  },
  {
    $unwind: "$job_docs"
  },
  {
    $facet: {
      totalDocs: [
        {
          $count: "value"
        }
      ],
      pipelineResult: [
        {
          $project: {
            _id: 1,
            jobTitle: 1,
            jobId: 1,
            jobDescription: 1,
            postedDate: 1,
            filter1: 1,
            filter2: 1,
            filter3: 1,
            createdAt: 1,
            updatedAt: 1
          }
        },
        { $match: filter },
        { $skip: query.skip },
        { $limit: query.limit }
      ]
    }
  },
  { $unwind: "$totalDocs" }
]).exec();
```

**Resultant Document: Demo**

```
{
  "totalDocs" : {
          "value" : 44
  },
  "pipelineResult" : [
          {
                  "_id" : ObjectId("5da7040e45abaee927d2d11a"),
                  "jobTitle" : "Foo",
                  "jobDescription": "Bar",
                  ...
                  "job_docs" : {...}
          },
          ...
  ]
}
```

Where `totalDocs` contain the count of documents in `value` property and `pipelineResult` would contain the documents of main pipeline operations.